# How to globally set Apache log folder and file using ServerName of VH

Tags: apache-2.4

I have multiple **Apache configuration files** `00-project1.conf`, `01-project2.conf`,... and would like to set for all these a scheme for the log file and level.

Currently, one example of such a configuration file looks like

```
Define LOG_PATH /my/path/to/the/log

<VirtualHost      XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80>
  DocumentRoot    "/what/ever/project11"
  ServerName      www.project11.org

  ErrorLog        ${LOG_PATH}/www.project11.org.error.log
  CustomLog       ${LOG_PATH}/www.project11.org.access.log common

  LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost      XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY:80>
  DocumentRoot    "/what/ever/project12"
  ServerName      www.project12.org

  ErrorLog        ${LOG_PATH}/www.project12.org.error.log
  CustomLog       ${LOG_PATH}/www.project12.org.access.log common

  LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
</VirtualHost>
```

**Question 1:** How can I globally set: (1) the `LOG_PATH` for all (or, even better, for a given list of) configuration files, (2) the `LogLevel`, and (3) the `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` depending on the `LOG_PATH` and on the `ServerName` ?

If this is too much to ask for, then...

**Question 2:** Is there a way, inside a **single configuration file** as above, to move the three settings `ErrorLog`, `CostomLog` and `LogLevel`outside the VHs to the beginning of the file ?

Example:

```
Define        LOG_PATH /my/path/to/the/log
ErrorLog      ${LOG_PATH}/${???ServerName???}.error.log
CostomLogLog  ${LOG_PATH}/${???ServerName???}.access.log common
LogLevel      alert rewrite:trace3

<VirtualHost      XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80>
  DocumentRoot    "/what/ever/project11"
  ServerName      www.project11.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Some context about the actual situation: in total, I am talking about 10-15 VHs, so I can just define the logging info 10-15 times individually. It nonetheless seemed stupid to do so. Some VHs are forwarded to locally running web services, some are forwarded to other domains, and some actually have document roots, only the logging is uniform (this seems to not allow a simple version of `mod_vhost_alias` to be used as suggested by @HBruijn).

Comment: A number of considerations: - With many similarly configured name based virtual hosts you may want use the template solution [mod_vhost_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) - With many virtual hosts that each have their own log  files you may quickly [run out of file descriptors](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/fd-limits.html)  - consider a generic log file with a custom log format that includes the virtual host name as an extra column and do post-processing to split that single file if you need that. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/split-logfile.html

Comment: In principle, these are reasonable suggestions, thanks. Unfortunately, they do not seem to apply in my situation. I updated the question, also with a local version of an approach.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't use a variable.

But...

When the filename in a [CustomLog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) (or the ErrorLog) directive is not absolute, in other words when it does not start with a leading <kbd>/</kbd> slash,  it is relative to the [ServerRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot). The ServerRoot can be set in your httpd.conf or it uses the compile time default.

You will typically see a symbolic link from SERVERROOT/logs to the desired file-system location used for your log directory and configuration settings such as:

Symbolic link:  `/usr/local/apache/logs --> /path/to/logs`

```
ErrorLog      "logs/www.project11.org.error.log"
CustomLog     "logs/www.project12.org.access.log common"
```

Comment: I agree that this could avoid the definition of the ``LOG_PATH`` in the beginning. On the downside, this would still refer all logs to the same folder, so if I ever start a completely separate project with other coworkers, I would not be able to split the log files anymore..